# Selecting item dynamically in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i am attempting to do a dynamic select here using rails and jquery. the code is as follows

```
<div class = "line_items">  

<%- calc = Hash[Item.all.map{|p| [p.id, p.quantity]}].to_json %>

<div class = "item"><%= f.collection_select :item_id,Item.all,:id,:title, :prompt => "Select a Item", input_html: {data:{calc: calc} %></div>

   <div class ="quantity"> <%= f.text_field :quantity %></div>
/*rest  of code*/
</div>
```

javascript for the view is as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.item').bind('change',function() {
    var selectElement = jQuery(this);
    var  itemSelected = jQuery('.item:selected').val();
    var wrapperDivElement = selectElement.parent(".line_items");
    var quantity= eval(selectElement.data("calc"))[itemSelected];
    jQuery(".quantity", wrapperDivElement).val(quantity);
  });
});
```

when i change the item i am getting the following error
`eval(selectElement.data("calc"))[itemSelected] is undefined` in firebug. Can anyone point out where i am going wrong? also any better way to get the quantity. i feel the method i am doing is crude. any guidance would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.item select').bind('change',function() {
    var selectElement = jQuery(this);
    var  itemSelected = selectElement.val();
    var wrapperDivElement = selectElement.parents(".line_items");
    var quantity= eval(selectElement.data("calc"))[itemSelected];
    jQuery(".quantity input", wrapperDivElement).val(quantity);
  });
});
```

i guess the value of itemSelected was not getting detected, hence the error. the above redefined code should work. But i strongly urge you not to get data like this. its better to do a json call or ajax call to get the related data from the controller. and use `parents` instead `parent` in the code:)

Answer (score 0):

Ik think you mixup the reference by index and the reference by ID. I'm no Javascript wizard, but you fill the hash with a list of . Then you get the 'val'-value in the change event. That contains an integer, but that is not the index.

Then you request in Javascript the item with index val, not the item with value val. Maybe javascript cannot distinguish between them because both need an Int...

it's this line:

```
var quantity= eval(selectElement.data("calc"))[itemSelected];
```